# How to access a class from another class?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, oop

I’m fairly new to OO. If I have two classes A and B that need to exchange data, or call each other’s methods, I need to be able to access an instance of class B from class A. Should I maintain the address of the instance object in a global variable? Should I appoint a (singleton) master class, and make (pointers to) instances of A and B properties of the master class? (AppDelegate comes to mind.)

Is there a straightforward by-the-book way to implement this? Somehow I‘m missing some "best practice" here. I’ve looked through Apple's examples, but didn't find an answer.

EDIT: Since I'm fairly new to MVC design patterns, my question is essentially "Who creates who"?

We're talking about an Audio Player here. 1. When the user selects a song, the UI displays its waveform by creating a viewController which creates the appropriate view. 2. When the user hits play, the UI displays a timeline while the song is playing by overlaying a new view over the waveform. Now, the latter view needs some info from the waveform display viewController. Right now, I'm storing a pointer to the viewController in an instance variable of my appDelegate. This works, but feels extremely strange.

Should I outsource the info that is needed by both classes to some third entity that every class can access easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes aren't simply departments of code. They are templates for the creation of objects, which you should think of as actors in your program, doing things within their areas of responsibility (which you define—you decide what each object does) and interacting with each other.

While you can handle a class as you would an object, classes generally do not talk to each other. Most of the time, you will create and use instances of the classes—which is what we normally mean by “objects”—and have those talking to each other. One object sends another a message, telling the receiver to do something or changing one of the receiver's properties. These messages are the interactions between your program's objects.

Those weird expressions in the square brackets are message expressions. Nearly everything you'll do with a class or object will involve one or more messages. You can send messages to classes the same as to objects, and classes can send messages just as objects can.

In Cocoa and Cocoa Touch, you typically have model objects, view objects, controller objects, data objects (such as NSString, NS/UIImage, and NSURL), and helper objects (such as NSFileManager). The classes you'll write for your application will mainly be model, view, and controller objects (MVC). The model represents (models) what the user will see themselves manipulating; the view displays the model to the user; the controller implements logic and makes sure the model gets saved to and loaded from persistent storage.

For more information, see [Object-Oriented Programming in Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/) and the [Cocoa Fundamentals Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/).

> Since I'm fairly new to MVC design patterns, my question is essentially "Who creates who"?

Controllers create and load the model, and load the views, and pass the model to the view for display. Certain controllers may also create other controllers.

It's good to keep a straightforward tree-like graph of ownership from a single root of your program—typically the application object—down through controllers to leaf objects in the models and views. If two objects own each other, that's a problem. If an object is not owned by anything outside of its own class (a singleton), that's usually a problem as well—a sign you need to think some more about where that code belongs. (Helper objects are the main exception; most of those are singletons. Again, see NSFileManager for an example. But they are few and far between.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the clarification. To come back to my issue at hand, you mean, my model and my view shouldn't talk to each other in the first place? Everything should be dispatched through the controller.

Comment: @Joe Völker: Correct. When using standard views, the controller should pass data objects from model to view and back. When using custom views, I typically give my custom view a property for a model object to display and edit. The difference is that standard views are designed to be generic, to work with nearly any model in any application, whereas a custom view I'll design for a specific model. The model never talks to the view and should talk to controllers as little and as generically as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Further situation analysis require more information. At first place you should more specify the relation between classes and what exactly do you mean by exchanging data.

Singletons should be generally avoided. If you want to exchange information it is usually sufficient to provide for example instance of the class A to the instance of the class B by some method or constructor. The instance of B is then capable of calling public methods (and accessing public properties) of the instance of A.

A little bit of "best practices" can be learn by searching up "Design Patterns".

Comment: More info: Two subviews of my main view represent my data. One is displaying a waveform, the other is displaying a timeline rovering over it. They need to access some common data. Right now the subviews are instantiated when needed and create their own representation, i.e., the waveform view class creates the waveform graphics in its drawRect: from the audio data.

Comment: I think it depends on the type of _common data_.  If they are related to input data, I would create different object representing the data and give it to both views. If it is related to the view itself, maybe you can wrap both views to an container or somewhat unify them different way. Or maybe you will come with something more clever...

Answer (score 1):

You should decide if one class can be an object of another class (encapsulation), or if one class can inherit from the other class (inheritance).  If neither of these is an option, then maybe you could make one class (or some of its members) static?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your contributions. Additionally, I found information on [this page](http://www.cocoalab.com/?q=node/24) very useful. It lays out MCV considerations for cocoa in a hands-on way and practical language.